# Mailx: cannot assign requested address using gmail

Tags: linux, centos, email, gmail

I'm having trouble to send email through **emailx** using gmail, after configuration, I'm having the following error:

```
 Resolving host smtp.gmail.com . . . done.
Connecting to 64.233.186.109:587 . . .Connecting to 64.233.186.108:587 . . .Connecting to 2800:3f0:4003:c00::6c:587 . . .could not connect: Cannot assign requested address
"/root/dead.letter" 10/277
. . . message not sent.
```

I did configure **/etc/mail.rc** with the following fields:

set smtp-use-starttls

set ssl-verify=ignore

set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587

set smtp-auth=login

set smtp-auth-user=

set smtp-auth-password=

set from="Server Mail"

I also tried to use port 465 but the same error occurs. Do I have to configure any certificate? Any other parameter I have to set on mail.rc file?

I'm using CentOS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is this machine located on the network?

Comment: It's a virtualized server behind a firewall, it's possible to update this machine's operational system using the internet.